# SQL query to get 10 last topics with replies

Tags: sql, database

I have a simple forum database and want to write SQL query to get 
10 last topics (threads) with replies from *3 or more unique posters*. 
Result: Topic (thread) name | Last message text | User name | Date 
[image: IMG1]

UPDATED:
Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT thread.thread_id, thread.thread_name, message.thread_id, 
COUNT(message.thread_id) 
FROM thread, message
WHERE message.thread_id = thread.thread_id
GROUP BY message.thread_id
HAVING COUNT(message.thread_id) >= 3
LIMIT 10
```

But it returns 10 topics (threads) with 3 or more *replies* (but not 3 or more unique posters)

UPDATE 2:

```
SELECT message.thread_id AS ID, thread.thread_name AS topic
FROM message INNER JOIN thread
ON message.thread_id = thread.thread_id
GROUP BY message.thread_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
LIMIT 10
```

This also returns 10 topics with 3 or more replies

UPDATE 3, thanks @shawnt00

```
SELECT thread.thread_name AS 'Topic', message_text AS 'Message', person_nickname AS 'Nickname', message_date AS 'Date'
FROM thread,
(
    SELECT thread.thread_id, MAX(message_date) AS last_date
    FROM thread 
    INNER JOIN message ON message.thread_id = thread.thread_id
    GROUP BY thread.thread_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT message.person_id) >= 3
) AS temp
INNER JOIN message
ON message.thread_id = temp.thread_id AND message.message_date = temp.last_date
INNER JOIN person ON person.person_id = message.person_id
WHERE thread.thread_id = temp.thread_id
ORDER BY message.message_date DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Please, provide some real data (as text). Is it SQL Server? MySQL?

Comment: And please edit your question and add your best attempt at resolving the issue.

Comment: What, pray-tell, is a "topic"?  It is nowhere in your data model.

Comment: oh, sorry, a topic is a thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with data as (
    select p.thread_id, max(message_date) as last_date
    from thread t inner join message m on m.thread_id = t.thread_id
    group by p.thread_id
    having count(distinct m.person_id) >= 3
)
select *
from data d
    inner join message m
        on m.thread_id = d.thread_id and m.message_date = m.last_date
    inner join person p on p.person_id = m.person_id;
```

The only assumption is that there can't be ties on dates. If you have analytic functions available then there are other approaches using those. I'm sure you can figure out how to get top 10.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! I've edited your code a little to make it work with MySQL. 

Is it possible to refine the table, and leave only fields: thread_name, message_text, person_nickname, message_date?

Comment: @SgtMaddonut Of course, just list the columns you want to return rather than `*`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need below query.
Assuming that you are using mysql so i used `Limit`function as you want last 3 unique row

```
        select distinct th.thread_name as Topic_name,  m.message_text,  p.person_nickname as User_name, m.message_date as Date from message m
            inner join thread th on m.thread_id=th.thread_id
            inner join persion p on p.persion_id=m.persion_id
order by message_date  desc
      Limit 3
```

But if the db is SQLSERVER Then use below query

```
      select distinct TOP(3) th.thread_name as Topic_name,  m.message_text,  p.person_nickname as User_name, m.message_date as Date from message m
            inner join thread th on m.thread_id=th.thread_id
            inner join persion p on p.persion_id=m.persion_id
order by message_date  desc
```